# $\int_a^b\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x) dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_a^b f_n(x) dx$

Tags: real-analysis

$\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of continuous (so also integrable) real functions on $[a,b]$ that is uniformly convergent and uniformly equicontinuous. I want to show $$\int_a^b\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f_n(x)}{{\color{red}{n^2}}} dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{{\color{red}{n^2}}}\int_a^b f_n(x) dx,$$
and I cannot figure out how to do this. I think to take the limit as $n\to\infty$ and use uniform convergence to the limit $f$ which will somehow allow the sum and integrals to switch, but I cannot figure out how to do this. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: In red.

Comment: If $f$ is any nonzero function with $\int_a^b f(x)dx = 0$, and if you take $f_n = f$ for each $n$, then the RHS is well-defined equal to $0$, but the LHS is not well defined since $\sum f_n$ does not converge pointwise.

Comment: The assumption should be that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent, not that $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly convergent.

Comment: With that change, the mere uniform boundedness of the $f_n$ guarantees that $\sum \frac{f_n(x)}{n^2}$ converges uniformly. (And weaker conditions than uniform boundedness would still guarantee it.)

Answer (score 1):

First note that $$\int_a^b\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{f_n(x)}{{{n^2}}} dx=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{{{n^2}}}\int_a^b f_n(x) dx$$ for each $N$ and that RHS of this equation tends to RHS of the equation we want to prove. Hence, it remains only to prove that LHS of this equation tends to LHS of the given equation. For this we use the following:

If $g_n \to g$ uniformly (with each $g_n$ continuous) then $\int_a^{b}g_n(x)dx \to \int_a^{b}g(x)dx$.

So it reamins only to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{f_n(x)}{{{n^2}}}$ converges uniformly to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f_n(x)}{{{n^2}}}$ as $N \to \infty$.

By M-test it is enough to show that $(f_n(x))$ is uniformly bounded. There exists $n_0$ such that $|f_n(x)-f_{n_0}(x)| <1$ for all $n \geq n_0$. Let $M$ be an upper bound for $|f_{n_0}|$ Then $|f_n(x)| <1+M$ for all $x$ for all $n \geq n_0$. Can you finish the proof now using the fact that each of the functions $f_1,f_2,...,f_{n_0-1}$ are bounded?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$. We need $$\int_a^b f(x)dx = \lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \int_a^b \sum\limits_{n=1}^N f_n(x)dx$$ Fix $\epsilon>0$, for $N$ big enough, $|f(x)-\sum\limits_{n=1}^N f_n(x)|\leq\epsilon$. Therefore $$|\int_a^b f(x)dx -\int_a^b \sum\limits_{n=1}^N f_n(x)dx| \leq \int_a^b |f(x) - \sum\limits_{n=1}^N f_n(x)|dx \leq \epsilon (b-a)$$

Comment: You need to show first that $f$ is integrable...

Comment: Of course you do, but it is straightforward and can be done exactly in the same way

Comment: @lucamac Thanks for this. I just edited the question a little bit since I do not see how we can do this  since $\frac{1}{n^2}$ cannot be factored out of this summation? Could you possibly help me see how to reach this?